# How to test login to GSuite calendar using Cypress

Tags: node.js, selenium, cypress

### Environment

- Windows 10
- NodeJs 8
- Cypress 3.1.2
- Selenium
- Chromium v59

### How to authenticate to Google calendar using Cypress?

I need to run automated tests on a Chrome extension that I am developing.
The first step is to authenticate/login to GSuite calendar.

I am using Cypress but it is not allowing me to login into GSuite calendar. Instead when "clicking sign-in" (from Cypress) it jumps to the `Next` button again.

### My code snippet

```
describe('Login',function() {
   it('Go to GSuite calendar', function() {
     cy.visit('https://www.google.com/calendar')
   })

   it('Login', function() {
     cy.get('#Email').type('my user')
     cy.get('#next').click()
     cy.get('#Passwd').type('my password')
     cy.get('#signIn').click()
   })
})
```

This fails and takes me to the `Next` button

### Screenshots

#### 1. Hit execute

[image: First image]

#### 2. At the end, it returns to the initial screen instead of logging me in

[image: Second image]

## My Try with Selenium & it works

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

# variables for userid & password
u = "JohnDoe@xxxx-labs.com"
p = "Mysecretpassword"

# chromedriver installation required for login through google chrome
driverpath = "C:/Users/pjain2/Desktop/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver"

# launch google calendar login page
d = webdriver.Chrome(driverpath)
d.get("https://www.google.com/calendar")

# fill email field send_keys for filling text
e = d.find_element_by_id("identifierId")
e.send_keys(u)

# find & click next button
d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='identifierNext']/content/span").click()
time.sleep(2)

# enter password
e = d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='password']/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")
e.send_keys("Mysecretpassword")
time.sleep(2)

# sign in
d.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='passwordNext']/content/span").click()
time.sleep(10)
```

### Screenshot of successfully login to Google calendar

[image]
I want to achieve the same thing with Cypress

Any pointers?

Comment: i tried with selenium using python and it works but i want through cypress

Comment: Check this [comment](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1380#issuecomment-368663427) by [Brian mann](https://github.com/brian-mann)

Answer (score 4):

In `spec.js` file, add the following code:

```
describe('Random VMR for ESG',function() {
    beforeEach(() => {
       cy.visit('https://www.google.com/calendar')
    })
      it('type email & password', function() {
        cy.get('#Email').type('my user')
        cy.get('#next').click()
        cy.get('#Passwd').type('my password')
        cy.get('#signIn').click()
    })   
})
```

In `support` folder, in `command.js`, add the following code:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', ()=> {
    cy.request({         // cy.request is not bound by any security and will bypass the login part
        method: 'POST' , // Post request to URL along with body
        url: 'https://www.google.com/calendar',
        body: {
            user: {
                email: 'my user',
                password: 'my password',
            }
        }
    })
     //server sends back the response JSON payload 
    .then((resp) => {      //token extracted from JSON payload and is saved in LocalStorage
     window.localStorage.setItem('jwt' , resp.body.user.token)
    })
})
```

In `spec.js` file, there is the code which just visits the URL and tests the `email` and `password` input type and signs in.

The problem was that is was redirecting the page back to the first page right after the sign in. To work around this behavior, we use `cy.request` in `commands.js` file since `cy.request` requests outside the constraints of the browser.  *i.e. it is not bound by any security.*

Once you have a proper **e2e** test around logging in, there’s no reason to continue to `cy.visit()` the login and wait for the entire page to load all associated resources before running any other commands. Doing so can slow down our entire test suite. Using `cy.request()`, we can bypass all of this because it automatically gets and **sets cookies** just as if the requests came from the browser itself.

Therefore a **POST** request is been sent along with the JSON payload or body. Now upon successfully validating the request body, our application code **extracts the token out of payload and save it in local storage** and also adds the token in all the request header so that the API server can authenticate subsequent request coming from our application.

When our application loads, it checks that the token is already in local storage or not, if it is then it goes ahead and and sets it on the request agent. This way, it will bypass the login part when you will test the **GSuite**.